# Minify javascript with Uglify and PhpStorm don't work

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, phpstorm-2017.2

I use latest PhpStorm 2017.2.3 and latest uglify.js.
In my Toolsettings id do this:

[image]

Than i add a testfile (test.js) in the module dir and 
take some code inside:

```
function test () {
var messsage = 'hello world';
alert(messsage);
}
```

The uglify result is this:

```
function test(){var messsage="hello world";alert(messsage)}
```

The tool don't minified the code, it only bring it in one line!
What i have to change in my settings to minify js-code?

Answer (score 3):

Add in the end of "Arguments:" [from docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2):

```
-c -m
```

and You'll get:

```
$FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js -c -m
```

Your code:

```
function test () {
  var messsage = 'hello world';
  alert(messsage);
}
```

will transform to:

```
function test(){alert("hello world")}
```